# Incrementing elements in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, increment

Well, since I'm practising "the Prolog logic" today and I found this unanswered problem in another thread here, I was wondering how it works.

> increment every element of list by its depth, example
>   increment([0,0,[0]],[1,1,[2]]) -> true

And I almost thought that I like this language... :))
Is something like that possible? Thanks.

Comment: If you get it and answer the question, I'll surely upvote you :)

Comment: its possible but for sure it wont be short predicate

Comment: four clauses below seem to be pretty short

Answer (score 2):

The following code does the job:

```
increment(X,Y):- increment(X,0,Y). 
increment([],_,[]) :- !.
increment([X|Xs],N,[Y|Ys]) :- !, N1 is N+1,
                              increment(X,N1,Y), increment(Xs,N,Ys). 
increment(X,N,Y):- Y is X+N.
```

Just to test it

```
?- increment([0,0,[0]],X).
X = [1, 1, [2]].

?- increment([0,0,[0,[0,0]]],X).
X = [1, 1, [2, [3, 3]]].
```

Comment: Wow, smart! I sent you an e-mail, sir @Alexander

Comment: I'll try to answer it tonight, sir @Norbert ;-)